# Searching date in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

In mongodb collection i have field called  event_startdate Which is in following format
event_startdate:2018-10-14 16:00:00.000 (type:date)

i am storing date and time together is this field and want to serach event which is happening today and using query given bellow

**var date= moment().format('YYYY-MM-D')
Event.find({ event_startdate:date}).exec()**

Since time also attached to event_startdate i am unable to fetch today's detail.
is there a way to find this?

Answer (score 0):

`var date= moment().format('YYYY-MM-D')` would give you a string which then you are trying to compare to an ISO date in mongo.

Try something among these lines:

```
db.getCollection('COLNAME').aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        $eq: [
          "2018-10-10",    // <--- You string date goes here
          {
            "$dateToString": {
              "date": "$date",
              "format": "%Y-%m-%d"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

This is using the [**`$expr`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) pipeline operator with [**`dateToString`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can also do using `find`.

```
db.getCollection('loginDetail').find({
      "$expr": {
        $eq: 
      [ "2018-09-21", { "$dateToString": { "date": "$eventDate", "format": "%Y-%m-%d"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    })
```